# How to merge two json object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have two json objects data and foo, i want to merge them and create a single json object. The resultant json should have all the values from foo and the values from data. so far i have something like this

**javascript:**

```
  $('#btn').click(function(){
            var imdbid=$('#tst').val();
            var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i="+imdbid+"&plot=full&r=json"
            $.ajax({
            url:url,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function (json) {
                 data=json
                 var foo=$('form').serializeJSON() // store json string 
                 var marged=$.extend(data,foo);
                 console.log(marged);
                }
            })   
            })
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
<label>imdb id:</label><input type="text"  id="tst" name="tst"/></form><br/>
<label>comment:-</label><input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" /><br/>
<label>link:-</label><input type="text" name="link" id="link" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="search"  id="btn"/>
</form>
```

the first object contains data returned from api and foo contains the values of form.i want to marge both object on a success function and send to php.
when i am trying to print out the data it's as follows

```
{Title: "Mother's Day", Year: "2016", Rated: "PG-13", Released: "29 Apr 2016", Runtime: "118 min"…}
Actors
:
"Britt Robertson, Jennifer Aniston, Julia Roberts, Timothy Olyphant"
Awards
:

imdbID
:
"tt4824302"
tst
:
"tt4824302"
```

it's getting first input value not showing the second two.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Note that `serializeJSON` returns a string, you can't merge a string with an object using `$.extend`, as it only merges two objects.

Comment: Then i have to convert that string to object first ?or is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: `$.extend(data, JSON.parse(foo));`, or use jQuery's `serializeArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the FORM on this line:

```
<label>imdb id:</label><input type="text"  id="tst" name="tst"/></form><br/>
```

... so it only gets the first input field  ; )

Comment: ahh yeah exactly. i knew there was something wrong with the form but didn't notice that.Thank you now it is working

Answer (score 1):

first change json to object than merge them as

```
data=json

var foo=$('form').serializeJSON();

marged=$.extend(JSON.parse(data),JSON.parse(foo));

console.log(marged);
```

Comment: it returns everything form the first object data but only there are `input name="comment"` and `input name="link"` are missing when console.log the data